# postfix ehlo response bug

Tags: size, limit, postfix-mta

I have postfix installed and working.
A customer asked to send a file larger than message_size_limit, so I tweaked the value and restarted postfix.

My customer said that the problem wasn't fixed, so I telnetted into the server several times and ran the ehlo command, and the "SIZE" responses were a mix of the original message_size_limit and the new one.
I restated the postfix service again, but got the same results. I thought it was caching the result, so I changed it again, and now I am getting all 3 different "SIZE" responses with several ehlo commands. Apparently, the EHLO response header is cached somewhere, but I don't know how to reset it. I'd prefer to not restart the machine.

Any insight about my experience?

It's been a couple of hours since the switchover - it appears to be consistently sending the correct size n the EHLO response. I would sure have liked it to be correct immediately after the change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main.cf of postfix is not refreshing when I type service postfix restart.

To find out what the PID is for the app locking my postfix, I typed:

```
netstat -tulpn | grep :25
```

The "25" is the port Postfix is serving on.

The results contain the PID/Name that is keeping postfix restarts from reloading the main.cf.

Then I terminate the program gently with:

```
kill -15 ####
```

Where #### is the PID of the program found in step 1.

Then I can perform:

```
service postfix restart
```

and the main.cf will be refreshed.